# Cycle selecting objects in Blender Python?

Tags: python, uv, select, looping

So basically, i have all these objects in my scene that I want to uv unwrap, the only issue is that if I do them all at once, blender crashes and stops working,
I was wondering if there was a way to cycle each object with a 10 second cool down, in a python script, so that every 10 second it will uv unwrap an object and then maybe hide it, and then move onto the next one, then when all the objects are hidden, it stop the loop.

I was wondering if it's possible in Blender Python?

Comment: use can use `time.sleep(10)`

Comment: I highly suggest using [Application timers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html) instead. `sleep` will completely lock the interface.